# import js script in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to import a javascript lib into my project without .d.ts files (for some reason it doesn't have), while sadly I cannot use 'import' or 'require' at the same time (the ts poject structure is old but cannot upgrade).Is there still any solution?The tsconfig.json may like the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "amd",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES2015"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "outFile": "./out/js/bundle.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./lib/lib.js",
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: alot of modules have a corresponding @types module you can install like [@types/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express) for express.js so maybe try and if there one for the library that you are using? :o

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, it has another type of description file like .d.ts named .api file. But ts compiler cant't recognize of it.So while I want to coding in vscode other than in it's original IDE(also uncomfortable to use),it's really hard.

Comment: what is the problem with your import? TypeScript yells at you because the js doesn't have type definition?

Comment: Because of the project problem, I can't use 'import xxx.js' directly,either can't use 'require'.